# Make IR variable numbering contiguous

Tags: llvm

After I add new instructions to the LLVM IR, the SSA notation numbering of variables does not remain contiguous.
E.g.:

```
%mul=
%mul1=
%mul2=
```

If I add a new 'mul' instruction after %mul using

```
CreateMul(op1,opt2,"mul");
```

then the output becomes as follows: OUTPUT:

```
%mul=
%mul3=
%mul1=
%mul2=
```

Is there any way to make the numbering contiguous in the IR?

Answer (score 2):

Do you want the library to go on and modify the names of all variables *after* your insertion point just to make the numbering contiguous? Why would you need this (?) - IMHO it doesn't make much sense. Keep in mind that the numbering is meaningless semantically - it's just a simple way to generate unique names.

If you insist, you can always just duplicate all instructions following the insertion point and they will have new variable names assigned. By "duplicate" I mean create new instructions which are clones of the existing ones and re-insert them into the IR instead of the existing ones.